# Passing column name as parameter to function in R language

Tags: r

I have got a function :

```
aggreg <- function(fileName, param){   
  contents <- read.csv(fileName, header=T)
  #print(contents)  #This displays all contents
  print(contents$param) #gives NULL
}

> aggreg("test.csv","Close.Price")
> NULL
```

Please guide further. Thanks:)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you need to use another way of accessing the columns in the dataframe than via `$`. There are two other ways:

1.

```
print(content[[param]])
```

2.

```
print(content[,param])
```

Comment: Saved my day. df[df[columnName] > 0, ]