# do.call for all dataframe columns with lazy evaluation and dplyr function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lazy-evaluation

My question is similar to these [enter link description here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/data-frame-columns-as-arguments-to-dplyr-functions/) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973056/in-r-pass-column-name-as-argument-and-use-it-in-function-with-dplyrmutate-a), but my problem is more complex as it requires multiple dplyr operations and lazy evaluation.

This is my function:

```
stats <- function(col_names){
require("dplyr")
data %>% 
group_by_(col_names) %>%
summarise(Count = n()) %>%
mutate(Percent = prop.table(Count)) -> temp
write.csv(temp, file=paste(col_names,".csv",sep="_"))}
```

Than, I want to pass every column name as an argument with do.call.

```
colnames <- names(data)

do.call(stats, as.list(col_names))
```

But I get a common error:

```
Error in (function (col_names)  : 
unused arguments           ("loans_approved_amount_limit_in_account", "loans_approved_amount_limit_in_ron")
```

The function works if I enter the column names seperately. But I have to over 1000 columns, and so I need to automate the process.

Comment: No links there, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why are you using `do.call`? Your function only takes one argument. Are you looking for `lapply` perhaps? Also, you're missing a `}`.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the links. 

I am using do.call because I want to pass a list of arguments, which are over 1000 column names of a dataframe. Dont know other why how to do this.

Comment: You're aware that `summarize_all` and `mutate_all` might also serve the same purpose without the need for the `lapply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`do.call` is used to supply multiple function arguments to a *single* execution of a function. For example, instead of writing `paste('c', 1:2)` we can use a list of arguments such that `do.call(paste, list('c', 1:2))` gives the same result.

So in your case, `do.call` is the same as running `stats(col1, col2, col3, ...)`. You can easily see that this won't work, since `stats` only takes one argument. That's why the error you get speaks about unused arguments.

What you want to do instead, is run your function *multiple* times with a single argument. One way to do that is `lapply`:

```
lapply(names(data), stats)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried: lapply(col_names, stats), but obviouslly I had it wrong.